# Independence of the LNR and DNR

Tags: law, international-law, ukraine

We abstract from all other countries.
There is some region in Ukraine that wants to secede from Ukraine.
What needs to be done according to Ukrainian and International law so that this region secedes from Ukraine?

The next question - why have they not done this until now? Or if they have already done it - what is the problem with their international recognition?

Comment: It's better to only post a single question per Q&A. Also, what do you mean with "the law"? Which law? The title could also be more meaningful.

Comment: @Trilarion Ukranian ant international laws of cource. The main question - is the last question. But before answer it, it is need to explain questions before

Comment: Just ask a single Q&A for each question you have and search before for possible duplicates.